# How do I change the size of the feature picture of a single post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, featured-post

Every time I select a featured photo for a single post, the size is always adjusted and it's massive. I have changed the size of the photo within WordPress, outside of WordPress, added code to functions, added widgets and still cannot seem to change the picture size. I may need hands on help as I have followed most videos on this topic and cannot figure it out. Please help! I think it has to do with the child theme I am using, which is Ace Blog, a child of Adventure Blog.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your problem in wordpress.stackexchange.com. Let me know actual link of single post page and also let me know which image size you want to display on that page via child theme. so I can help you.

Comment: What's the code being used to display your featured image? And which registered image size is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the picture and the size still the same, it's either your code that displays it or just browser caching.

If you wanted to view the image after you update the size, try using incognito.

I'm being quite abstract here, give more info if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going into the html and figuring out what size simple images was using and changed it. Thanks!